# How can I get a handle on ng-repeat children elements in my custom directive?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to build a custom directive that rearrange its content as a grid.
I want to transclude the result of an `ng-repeat` directive and then reorder the resulting elements.

The problem is when I call the `element.children()` method inside the link function, I have an empty array because the `ng-repeat` directive is not yet rendered and is interpreted as a comment.

Otherwise, the directive works great if its content is 'static'.

The HTML

```
<grid n='6'>
    <div ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]"></div>
</grid>
```

My directive with only the interesting pieces of code:

```
app.directive('grid', [function () {
    return {

        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",

        link: function (scope, grid, attrs) {

            // With an ngRepeat transcluded, els result in an empty array
            var els = grid.children();

            // ...
    }; 
}]);
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Within your link function you can try using $timout(function() { //access grid children},0);

Comment: That indeed works, but is this method reliable ?

Comment: Actually you child template get rendered after post link function so you need to add $timout, it would work as it introduces some delay.

Comment: Hey @Laurent was my suggestion able to help you in any ways? Please share your findings

Comment: @scniro: Thank you for taking the time to reply. I posted the question nearly two years ago so I have moved on now, however I'm sure your answer will be useful to others running into it !

Comment: @Laurent I hear yea, and figured as much. I definitely found the info helpful, especially the second example - I didn't know we could even do that. Could you check it out and would you be willing to accept the answer if you found it interesting as well? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To achieve reordering, you have several options:

1. Manipulate DOM. IMHO, this is the least preferred way, it's not very angular.
2. Re-order the array ([1, 2, 3]) which is used in `ngRepeat` in your linking function.
3. Use `orderBy` filter ([doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3aorderBy))

I've created a plunk to demonstrate 2 and 3, hope it can help. http://plnkr.co/edit/vrgeBoJZiG6WMu4Rk46u?p=preview

Comment: I may have mislead you with the 'reorder' term. My goal was more to rearrange the elements as a grid (for example 3 elements / row). Anyway thank you ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to approach this. The easiest and most common solution you will see is as comments suggest - leverage [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) as such...

```
.directive('grid', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, grid, attrs) {
            $timeout(function() {
                console.log(grid.children());
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

> $timeout([fn], [delay], [invokeApply], [Pass]);
>
> [...]
>
> `invokeApply` - If set to false skips model dirty checking, otherwise will invoke fn within the $apply block. (**default: true**)

Calling `$timeout` will force a `$digest` cycle - so by the time you log the children - the `ng-repeat` directive will be "done." The race with `ng-repeat` is the crux of the issue here - for it's still doing it's job by the time we enter our `link` function.

---

Another way you can solve this - which is certainly less common - but does a great job at illustrating a more detailed sequence of events, is as follows...

```
.directive('grid', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, grid, attrs) {
            scope.$on('repeat-done', function () {
                console.log(grid.children());
            });
        }
    }
}])
.directive('ngRepeat', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last)
                scope.$root.$broadcast('repeat-done');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Here we are unobtrusively extending `ng-repeat` to invoke a function upon completion - and we can subscribe to this via `$on` in our `link` function.

---

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/g1jjdro4/) - simple demo showcasing both approaches